# Add Programmed Radio

Tags: sonos

I'm following the "add programmed radio"  guide.  I got stuck  a couple of months ago.  And thought I'd try again since the 10.2 release specifically mentions it.

I'm testing with the sonos app on Android and a Sonos ONE (gen1 10.3)

I cannot get the speaker to make any context requests to the cloudqueue radio endpoint.

When the manifest file has a radio endpoint defined.
I get the error "unable to play selected item"  ( and no requests are made to smapi or cloudqueue server )

If I remove the radio endpoint it makes a call to the smapi server.

This is the soap response I'm using to create an item that can trigger the radio endpoint.

I'm wondering if the mediaMetadata response is correct.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:getMetadataResponse
        xmlns:ns2="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
        <ns2:getMetadataResult>
            <ns2:index>0</ns2:index>
            <ns2:count>1</ns2:count>
            <ns2:total>1</ns2:total>
            <ns2:mediaMetadata>
                <ns2:id>prad:87</ns2:id>
                <ns2:itemType>program</ns2:itemType>
                <ns2:title>radio channel a</ns2:title>
            </ns2:mediaMetadata>
        </ns2:getMetadataResult>
    </ns2:getMetadataResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I've got a proxy set up so I can monitor the traffic and payloads.
I do see some calls to the reporting endpoint when playing the sample tracks in the sample server.   But never seen a single call to the radio endpoint.

Below is the manifest.  It's just a copy of what's in the docs.

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.0",
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "type": "reporting",
      "uri": "https://1222b45e.ngrok.io/flight/radioz/"
    },{
      "type": "radio",
      "uri": "https://1222b45e.ngrok.io/flight/radiox/"
    }
  ],
  "presentationMap": {
    "uri": "https://1222b45e.ngrok.io/flight/assets/presentationmap.xml",
    "version": 2
  },
  "strings": {
    "uri": "https://1222b45e.ngrok.io/flight/assets/strings.xml",
    "version": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few tips that might help:

1. What is your manifest endpoint? Is it HTTPS? If not, then the player won't download it. However, since you're getting calls to your reporting endpoint, that probably is not it.
2. What does your `radio` endpoint look like? Does it end in a `/`? If not, you won't get requests. This is a bug on the Sonos end that is being addressed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am using https.  The trailing slash sounded promising. Didn't seem to have any effect though.   Reporting endpoint still gets called but radio items still throw an error without making any requests.

Comment: @Jarro, have you verified that you have a generic `context` endpoint? For instance, `/context` is not enough, you have to have a specific endpoint `/context/:radioId:`, or else you might not see the request. For example, `/context/prad:87`. Also, please make sure that you are properly decoding the url, since `:` will be `%3a`, so the request would look like `GET /context/prad%3a87`.

Comment: Yes, if there were any context requests I'd see them in the logs.    This is from a couple of months ago,  but it's still the same behavior.   It will request the manifest.   I can trigger some reporting requests.  But nothing happens when I click on the program item  in the sonos app.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/soqyq.png